# Find sum of an unknown sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Given $a_1,a_2...,a_n$ to be integers bigger than $0$ with different of $2$ from each other and have prime factor smaller than $5$. Let $S_n=\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+...+\frac{1}{a_n}$ then find $S_n$

We are giving 4 answers
\begin{equation}
A.S_n<3\\ B.8<S_n<12\\ C.3\leq S_n\leq 8\\ D.12\leq S_n<20
\end{equation}
I dunno how to approach this but think for this kind of sum of fraction it'd be hard to have the sign $\leq$ and since in the giving it has prime factor smaller than $5$ so I think $B.8<S_n<12$ is the answer. ( This problem might have some issue at " different of $2$ with each other" because it is not in English and moreover I also have some trouble understand that phrase too But I think that's how it is ) please help

**Edit** as stated in the comment by @Oussema, he/she suggested that " different of $2$ from each other" actually means pairwise distinct, as in each two terms are different.

Comment: I think the "different of 2 with each other" actually means pairwise distinct, as in each two terms are different.

Comment: @Oussema maybe something like that. Should I edit it or just let it be?

Comment: You should edit it to make it clear.

Comment: "...and have prime factor smaller than 5".  What does this mean, that either $a_1, a_2, \cdots$ are all even numbers or are all multiples of $3$?

Comment: @user2661923 I think that mean $a_k=2^m×3^n$ for some $k$ integer

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure that I understand your last comment.  Are you saying that when examining the prime factorization of **each** of $a_1, a_2, \cdots,$ the only primes that will appear in each prime factorization are $2$ and $3$?

Comment: @user2661923 Yes something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, I wouldn't give more than a hint, because the OP hasn't really shown work.  However, this problem is **weird** because I'm unsure how to interpret:

> Given $a_1,a_2...,a_n$ to be integers bigger than $0$ with different of $2$ from each other and have prime factor smaller than $5$.

It's been suggested that one of the constraints is that $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n$ are all distinct.

However, it is **very** unclear what the other constraint signifies.  Does this mean that for every element $a_k \in \{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n\}$, that there exist non-negative integers $r,s$ such that $a_k = 2^r \times 3^s$?

In an attempt to **reverse-engineer** an answer, I'm going to assume that the answer to the question posed in the previous paragraph is **yes**.

Partition the possible values of $a_n = 2^r \times 3^s$ by the exponent $r$.  That is, let $T_0$ denote all integers of the form $(2^0 \times 3^s)$, $T_1$ denote all integers of the form $(2^1 \times 3^s)$ and so forth.

Then, the sum of the reciprocals of the elements taken from $T_k$ must be less than $(1/2^k) \times [1 + (1/3) + (1/9) + \cdots] = (1/2^k) \times (3/2)$.

Since $k$ can range through all of the non-negative integers, we have that the sum of the reciprocals of $T_0 \cup T_1 \cup T_2 \cdots$ must be less than

$$ (3/2) \times [1 + (1/2) + (1/4) + \cdots] = (3/2) \times 2 = 3.$$

Comment: Sorry about that, but I can't even understand what the problem is talking about ( even though it is in my language, but I'm pretty sure the authur just translate this problem from foreign ) that's why I come here so I could get both problem and how to solve it. Thank you for your solution

Answer (score 2):

If the numbers $a_n$ are pairwise distinct and they have $2$ or $3$ as prime factors, then the sum is $$\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\frac16+\frac18+\frac19+\ldots +\frac{1}{2^i3^j}< 3$$
Indeed $$ \sum _{i=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2^i3^j}=3$$

**Edit**

$$\sum _{j=0}^{\infty }\sum _{i=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2^i3^j}=\sum _{j=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{3^j}\sum _{i=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2^i}=\sum _{j=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{3^j}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac12}=2\sum _{j=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{3^j}=$$
$$=2\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac13}=2\cdot\frac{3}{2}=3$$

Comment: Why ? The last step is missing details , you wouldn't let your students get away with this 

Comment: @jimjim Thank you for the useful comment: I edited adding details. TBF I no longer have "students" since I am retired, happily retired :)

Comment: Haha , one can never retire from maths , like your answer , can see how it could be generalised to include 2,3,..., n , just not sure if the answer will be n for the general case